# jsoup: Как заменить текст не нарушая html?

Tags: java, jsoup

Имеется html документ и хотелось бы в него внести изменения в тексте всех тегов.

Вместо:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Название</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>Название2<br>
<div>Тоже</div>
<p>Название3<br></p>
<table><tr><td>Еще</td></tr></table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Хотелось бы сделать вот это:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Nazvanie</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>Nazvanie2<br>
<div>Toje</div>
<p>Nazvanie3<br></p>
<table><tr><td>Esho</td></tr></table>
 </body>
</html>
```

То есть изменение текстов в тегах, не изменяя саму структуру документа.

Я примерно понимаю, что скорее всего это надо делать форичем, перебирать каждый тег, хватать с него весь текст, конвертировать и вставлять заново на место, и так со следующим тегом... Но вот как это исполнить...

Спасибо заранее!!!

---

Спасибо, tutankhamun!!! Как я понимаю, цикл я не использую по назначению. Подскажите как результат цикла вывести в файл? Надеюсь в цикле все делаю верно? Спасибо за терпение!

```
String sitePath = "http://www.***.info/";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(sitePath).get();

String title = doc.html();
String convertedHTML = changeTxt(title);

for (Element element : doc.select("*")) {
    if (element.children().size() > 0) continue;
    element.text(changeTxt(element.text()));
}


File fileDir = new File("Sample.html");
Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileDir), "UTF8"));

out.write(convertedHTML);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Comment: Текст изначально известен или нужно весь русский текст заменить транслитом ?

Answer (score 6):

Если первый документ создает ваше приложение - перепишите его и пользуйтесь шаблонизаторами.

Если первый документ вы получаете "со стороны" и, судя по метке вы собираетесь пользоваться JSOUP, то тут тоже есть варианты:

По вашему примеру получается, вы хотите транслитеровать все тексты. Тогда действительно:

```
for (Element element : doc.select("*")) {
    // Если внутри данного тега есть другие теги
    if (element.children().size() > 0) continue;
    element.text(Translit.do(element.text()));
    // Translit.do() реализуете сами или поищите существующие реализации
}
```

Если нужно изменять какие-то тексты на строго определенные места (теги), то тут вам понадобится составить словарь селекторов которые вы хотите найти и тех текстов которые вы хотите вставить. Затем перебираем словарь, ищем нужные теги и вставляем значения словаря

```
HashMap<String, String> replaces = new HashMap<String, String>();
// тут заполняем словарь
// потом перебираем ключи словаря, находим нужные HTML-теги и меняем их тексты
for (String selector : replaces.keySet()) {
    String text = replaces.get(selector);
    doc.select(selector).text(text);
}
```

Недостатки приведенного кода в том, что теги не всегда содержат только текст. Бывает так:

```
<div>text 1 <span>text 2</span> text 3</div>
```

Тогда процесс несколько усложняется. Для каждого найденного элемента нужно перебирать текстовые узлы

```
for (TextNode textNode : element.textNodes()) {
    // Ну и дальше меняем так как нам надо. Например для транслита:
    textNode.text(Translit.do(textNode.text()));
}
```

Comment: Большое вам спасибо, tutankhamun, за пример:

for (Element element : doc.select("*")) {
    // Если внутри данного тега есть другие теги
    if (element.children().size() > 0) continue;
    element.text(Translit.do(element.text()));
    // Translit.do() реализуете сами или поищите существующие реализации
}

Это то что нужно, но... Я воспользовался вашим циклом и сконвертировал весь текст... но где же теги? Как снова поместить текст в теги? Я начинающий программист java, только учу, так что сорри если что...

Comment: Я сделали транслит сайта, по заданному шаблону меняются шрифты. Проблема в том,  чтобы избавить от конвертации теги <script> и <style>. Метод, который вы привели с циклом форич отличный, но как вернуть текст в теги?

Comment: 1. element.text(text) как раз помещает текст в теги. В чем именно проблема? 2. Чтобы исключить теги `<script>` и `<style>` из рассмотрения, сделайте условие `element.tagName() != ...`